# Cannot find the ew.txt file running example from package fanplot in R

Tags: r

I am trying to follow an example in the package fanplot but I cannot find the ew.txt file.
I would be grateful for your help.

```
data(ew)
plot(ew)

## Not run: 
plot(ew.mcmc)

##
##Create your own (longer) MCMC sample
##
# data
r <- diff(log(ew))
r <- ts(exp(r) - 1, start(ew))

library("R2OpenBUGS")
# write model file:
ew.bug <- dget(system.file("model", "ew.txt", package = "fanplot"))
write.model(ew.bug, "ew.txt")
# take a look:
file.show("ew.txt")
# run openbugs
ew.mcmc <- bugs(data = list(N = length(r), H = 25, r = c(r), p = c(ew)),
                inits = list(list(a = exp(12), psi = 0.5, itau2 = 0.5)),
                param = c("alpha", "psi", "tau", "r.new", "p.new", "y.sim"),
                model = "ew.txt", 
                n.iter = 11000, n.burnin = 1000, n.chains = 1, n.thin = 1)

## End(Not run)
```

Comment: @adam-888 I dropped the ew.txt BUGS file from the fanplot package when I released the tsbugs package. See the updated example code in the manual and/or vignette of the fanplot package to run these models and plot the fans. My apologies for the confusion. It seemed liked the most logical thing to do at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is in `R_LIBS/fanplot/model/` where `R_LIBS` is the location of your package library.

In the example code, the file is found via `system.file()`:

```
system.file("model", "ew.txt", package = "fanplot")
```

and then the next line writes the model to a the file `ew.txt` in the **working** directory. It is not clear which `ew.txt` you want. If the one that comes with the package find it in `R_LIBS` as above. Or download the source tarball from CRAN (the `tar.gz` from the [package page on cran](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fanplot/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, I looked in the R_LIBS/fanplot/ directory and there is no subdirectory: model. I also looked in the other subdirectories in fanplot but cannot find ew.txt anywhere.

Comment: What OS are you on? I just looked and version 1.0 had the `model` directory in the wrong place in the package sources so it never gets installed (it should be `PKG_ROOT/inst/model` but was `PKG_ROOT/model`). Version 1.1 fixes this problem but it is not available yet for Windows and MacOS X. My Answer pertains to version 1.1; the file doesn't exist in an installed package with 1.0.

Comment: Thanks very much for all your help. I am on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

When you run this code in an interactive session, use `getwd` to see what your working directory is. This should be the directory which contains the saved text file.